# how to use Pagination with swipe using swift 3

Tags: swift3, pagination, tableview, uipagecontrol

How to Implement Pagination  In PageControl , please suggest any demo or tutorials, i want to load my data in different page , different page has different data from rest Api ,so how to do it , suggestions are appriciated .!

Comment: So Many library available...[1](https://github.com/touchlane/SlideController) , [2](https://github.com/EndouMari/TabPageViewController) , [3](https://github.com/west-east/XQPageController) , [4](https://github.com/hirohisa/PageController)

Comment: swipe pages according to data@KetanOdedra

Comment: UP & down swipe pages and change data according to my Rest Api data @KetanOdedra

Comment: sorry i did not understand your question properly

Comment: how to use paged based application with Tableview for loading data in same viewcontroller , but data will be chnage according to page swipe @KetanOdedra

Comment: Do you want to call API after a certain amount of data showed in tableView/CollectionView?  for example : firstPage -> yourUrl.com/item/1 then secondPage ->  yourUrl.com/item/2 ?

Comment: yes exactly i want this type data@NahidRaihan